# How to change input type using dropdown menu in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field and a dropdown. Whenever I change my DropDown list , accordingly textbox should get change.

my code

```js
$('body').on('change', "#fieldType", function(){
     var  changeType  = $(this).val();
     console.log(changeType);
     var rohit = $('.createDynamicBox.highLighted').find('input').attr("type=changeType");
     console.log(rohit);
  });
```

```css
.formGroup{border:solid 1px red; margin-top:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="createDynamicBox highLighted" data="singleLineTextBtn">
   <label for="singeText3U17">Single line text</label>
   <input type="text" value="" id="singeText3U17">
</div>
<div class="formGroup">
   <label for="fieldType">Field Type</label>
   <select id="fieldType">
  <option value="text">Text</option>
         <option value="number">Number</option>
  <option value="password">Password</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$('#singeText3U17').get(0).type = changeType;`

try to this

```js
$('body').on('change', "#fieldType", function(){
     var  changeType  = $(this).val();
     console.log(changeType);
     var rohit = $('.createDynamicBox.highLighted').find('input').attr("type=changeType");
     console.log(rohit);
   
   $('#singeText3U17').get(0).type = changeType;
    
  });
```

```css
.formGroup{border:solid 1px red; margin-top:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="createDynamicBox highLighted" data="singleLineTextBtn">

<label for="singeText3U17">Single line text</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="singeText3U17">

</div>
    
    
    
    <div class="formGroup">
              <label for="fieldType">Field Type</label>
              <select id="fieldType">
               <option value="text">Text</option>
               <option value="number">Number</option>
               <option value="password">Password</option>
              </select>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.prop("type",changeType)` instead of `attr()` to change the input's type

```js
$('body').on('change', "#fieldType", function(){
     var  changeType  = $(this).val();
     console.log(changeType);
     var rohit = $('.createDynamicBox.highLighted').find('input').prop("type",changeType);
     console.log(rohit);
  });
```

```css
.formGroup{border:solid 1px red; margin-top:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="createDynamicBox highLighted" data="singleLineTextBtn">

<label for="singeText3U17">Single line text</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="singeText3U17">

</div>
    
    
    
    <div class="formGroup">
              <label for="fieldType">Field Type</label>
              <select id="fieldType">
               <option value="text">Text</option>
               <option value="number">Number</option>
               <option value="password">Password</option>
              </select>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change type attribute with `attr` method, because IE does not support fot this operation use `prop` instead.

```
var rohit = $('.createDynamicBox.highLighted').find('input').prop("type", changeType);
```